# Trying to clone SVN repository to local machine using the git svn clone command

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

Trying to clone `SVN` repository to local machine using the `git svn clone` command below:

```
git svn clone http://svn/java mirror.git`
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Did you mean one of these?
        fsck  
        show
```

Comment: Which version of git are you using?

Comment: is git-svn installed? if not try: `sudo apt-get install git-svn`

Comment: Try `git svn help` to check if you have git-svn installed.

Comment: What is your operating system? `Linux` (if so what distro), `Windows` (`CygWin`, `MinGW`)? And what is your `git` version (`git --version`)?

Comment: the issue was I did not have git-svn loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install "yum install git-svn"